# MiKTeX compilation on my new notebook (Windows10)

Tags: windows, miktex2.9

I bought a new notebook (ACER SWIFT1) with Windows10.
This computer has only only 256G SSD therefore it is preformated into only one disk (C).
I installed MiKTeX.
But some strange issues happened....
The file I compiled perfectly on my previous notebook break down without error message.
Is it possible because this C disk do not allow user to write?
Should I partition my disk into C and D?

Comment: What does 'break down without error' exactly mean?

Comment: I don't think this is related to permissions, but your installation. What does "break down" mean?

Comment: The log file simply break at there. See the following....(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[DFT_TX3.TTC]/OT:script=hani;language=dflt;"

 [3

]
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/DFT_HZ5.TTC(0)/m/sl' in size <12> not availa
ble
(Font)              Font shape `TU/DFT_HZ5.TTC(0)/m/it' tried instead on input 
line 9.
 [4

]

Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 9.

[5]) [6] (history.tex
 第\CJKnumber {1}章

Comment: The last output is \CJKnumber .... I have tried various files (I wrote many books) they all seems stop at the first \CJKnumber